# Highcharts DotNet: Would it be at all possible to label Plotlines

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I was wondering if it was possible to some how label PlotLines. Either labeling the lines directly or adding an item to a legend. I have been trying to find a way, but have not found one yet.

```
new XAxisPlotLines
{
    Value = upperspec,
    Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red,
    DashStyle = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.DashStyles.ShortDash,
    Width = 2,
    Label = new XAxisLabels { Text = "Label Here" } // This does not work, but I want something with this functionality
}
```

Thank you! Please let me know if there is any misunderstanding in the question.

Edit
**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version 2.0 of DotNet.Highcharts library it's possible to add text on plot lines.
For example:

```
new YAxisPlotLines
{
    Value = 932,
    Color = Color.FromName("red"),
    Width = 1,
    Label = new YAxisPlotLinesLabel
        {
            Text = "Theoretical mean: 932",
            Align = HorizontalAligns.Center,
            Style = "color: 'gray'"
        }
}
```

Also you can see how is used in the sample project. Download from here: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Label here" },
...
*PlotLines = new[]
{
     new XAxisPlotLines
     {
         ...
     }
}*
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that is not exactly what I want. That put's a title on the XAxis, but I would like a title next to the plotted line. I will update with a screen shot.